# How to write codes in a file using php

Tags: php, file

I want to write php codes in a file using php

**Try**

```
$cache = "<?php include_once 'a.php';" . $var .ob_get_contents();
file_put_contents('page.php', $cache);
```

**Error**

```
syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)
```

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong, have a try with this instead to get started:

```
<?php
$cache = file_get_contents('a.php');
file_put_contents('page.php', $cache);
```

The documentation of `file_put_contents()` clearly states that it requires *two* arguments (or more). First the path to the file to write to, second the content to write into the file. You provided only a single argument, since you concatenated two things using the `.` operator.

However in this case: wouldn't it be easier to just copy the file instead?

Your comment below suggests that you indeed want to concatenate some variables value to what you write into the output file. Just concatenate it then:

```
<?php
$cache = file_get_contents('a.php');
$cache .= $var;
$cache .= ob_get_contents();
file_put_contents('page.php', $cache);
```

Comment: Sorry, no, there is no such syntax error in the code above. Either the error is raised inside other parts of your code, or you made a mistake when you copied that code. Are you really sure you replaced the `.` with a `,` as I pointed out? Also make sure you cleared your browsers cache...

Comment: yes, if i add a.php in `file_get_content()` then how can i add the variable?

Comment: Ah, so you have some additional stuff you want to write? I was not sure when reading your question, this looked to me like "mixed attempts"... Anyway: if you just want to concatenate some variables content, then just do so! I added an example to the answer.

Comment: yes i have additional variables and other contents to put in the file along with the php codes

Comment: Your 2nd Answer Works. Thank you for this idea. Well I edit some code but idea was yours. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

`$cache` is php variable so write inside php code also check syntax in [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

```
<?php
$cache = include_once 'a.php' . $var .ob_get_contents();
file_put_contents('page.php' , $cache);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to split up your `<?php` since PHP's behaviour can be a bit weird if it finds another open-tag, even if it is in a string.
Try this:

```
$cache = "<" . "?php include_once 'a.php';" . $var .ob_get_contents();
```